# Not able to change column names using Pandas and SQLAlchemy in an ETL process from CSV to a SQL Server DB

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I’m using engine.execute() to run raw SQL to change a column name in SQL Server like so:

```
engine.execute('exec sp_rename 'table_name."Old Column Name"', 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN'')
```

I’m not getting any errors and the logs show the line I'm trying to execute but changes aren’t reflected in the table.

Looking at the logs:

```
2020-03-16 09:33:15,671 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine exec sp_rename 'table_name."Old Column Name"', 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN'
2020-03-16 09:33:15,671 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2020-03-16 09:33:15,769 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN [Column Name] date
2020-03-16 09:33:15,769 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2020-03-16 09:33:15,773 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

It shows where I'm trying do the column rename but it doesn't commit. After that, it shows where I'm changing a column data type and shows that it commits. If I copy the line that I’m trying to execute from the logs into DataGrip console and run it, the name change is successful.

Note: All of the column names from the CSV’s have spaces and many have special characters. Surrounding the column names in brackets has taken care of the issue in other places where I’m executing raw SQL. I’ve experimented with brackets and double quotes in DataGrip console, so I don’t think it’s an issue in this case. I could certainly be wrong though.

Any help is appreciated.

python 2.7

pandas 0.20.3

sqlalchemy 1.3.13

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are missing quotes there?

Comment: Thank you! I'm looking forward to getting more involved.

Where do you think I may be missing quotes?

Comment: Hi @DarkMarcos, whatever quotation mark you choose for the whole string, you need to escape the corresponding inner (double) quote with \. If you use ' you need to escape inner with \'; The same with " -> \". I'm wondering if it is a typo here or you have like this in your code. It could be the cause of the trouble.

Comment: @Ictus, I'm escaping the inner quotes. I didn't include that in the code here to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

So, after nearly a week of working on this issue, I found a solution. Not sure why yet but using engine.execute() with sp_rename wasn't committing the transaction. I had to commit the transaction by creating a session and explicitly committing. It looks something like this:

```
engine = create_engine('your_db_url')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = Session()
session.execute('exec sp_rename 'table_name."Old Column Name"', 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN'')
session.commit()
```